# Create an OS C++ Specific API

Tags: c++, header, multiplatform

I need to create some API, with which, by calling a function, the correct one for the current operating system will be called.

So I went with that :

main.cpp :

```
#include "api.h"
int main() {
    helloWorld();
    return 0;
}
```

api.h :

```
void helloWorld();
```

api.cpp :

```
void helloWorld() {
    #ifdef __gnu_linux__    
        printf("Hello World of Linux");
    #endif
    #ifdef WIN32
        printf("Hello World of Windows");
    #endif
}
```

But this doesn't satisfy me. When I'll have big functions, such as the one to get all childs of a process under Linux, and many others, I'll have a problem of space, of visibility to maintain the code.

I tryed to include different headers depending on the underlying OS, but this doesn't work very well, I can't have two headers (one for Windows, one for Linux) and only one C++ file.

So, do you know how I could separate the code for Linux and Windows so I end up with two file (one only for Linux and one only for Windows) with one header file that will have a `#ifdef` condition ? I couldn't make it work ...

Comment: Are you expecting the same binary to run on Windows *and* Linux?

Comment: Just put the .cpp files in different directories, and build using the proper files for each system. The build parameters will likely be different anyway.

Comment: @Roger : Yes, I need to make it work for both

Comment: No @Xaltar, you won't have the same binary working for Windows and Linux (that's impossible for C++, since it generates native code). You'll have both programs generated from the same source. That's different.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant : "I want my code to be compilable both for Windows and Linux".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it the following way:

main.cpp and api.h does not suffer any modification.

api.cpp:

```
#ifdef linux
    #include "linux_api.h"
#endif
#ifdef WIN32
    #include "windows_api.h"
#endif

void helloWorld() {
    #ifdef linux
        helloWorld_linux();
    #endif
    #ifdef WIN32
        helloWorld_win32();
    #endif
}
```

Then you need to provide `linux_api.h`, `linux_api.cpp` and `windows_api.h`, `windows_api.cpp`. The advantage is that this four files are already platform specific. You only have to create the "glue code" in `api.cpp` for each function.

linux_api.h:

```
void helloWorld_linux();
```

linux_api.cpp:

```
#include "linux_api.h"

#include <cstdio>

void helloWorld_linux()
{
    std::printf( "Hello world from linux..." );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `api.cpp` part while trying this. I'll go on with that for now, but I can't get past the `_linux` and `_win32` part differenciation ? There's no way ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but don't get it. Are you having trouble applying the solution or not? Please explain yourself a little bit.

Comment: Sorry. Your solution is perfect. But, is there a way to have `api.h` with only `void helloWorld();` and incluing the proper Windows or Linux `.cpp` file with #ifdef ?

Comment: The only way to do that is the use of make, and maybe autotools and autoconf, as @Bo Persson suggested, for building your app. I can't think of any other way.